# Swift class without initializer working?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

Could you please tell me why that code (class) is working in playground?
If I understand properly there should be init or something that can be used by "blank initializer"?

```
class Shape{
    var numberOfSides = 0
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
    return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }
}

var shapeA = Shape()
shapeA.simpleDescription()
shapeA.numberOfSides = 7
var shapeDescription = shapeA.simpleDescription()
shapeA.simpleDescription()
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: It's documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID213

Answer (score 1):

If all the stored properties are given default values, as here, the class does not need to have an explicit initializer.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift an init override is only required in certain cases.

For instance, if you hadn't put a default value on that `numberOfSides` var then you would have to have an init to provide the default value.

Or you would have had to make it optional which gives it a `nil` default value.

This is all explained in the iBook by apple.

Comment: Optional properties have the default value `nil`, so your second example is a special case of the first one.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that is what I meant but didn't write it explicitly. I've edited my answer now. Thanks.